# How can I make the task body empty when moving a task to calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I usually write different tasks in Outlook tasks then I move those to Outlook calendar as appointments. However, when I move them the body of the task will contain texts that I didn't add such as Status, Owner, etc. Is there a way that I remove this default text so next time when I move a task to calendar I dont find such text.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I remove this default text so next time when I move a task to calendar I dont find such text.

No. You need to delete the default text manually when you change it to a calendar item.

Instead, i think it's more convenient that you could first create an appoint ment and move it to task.